# Parsing nested java classes (POJO) using Java 8 to invoke a method and obtain the returned result

Tags: java, spring-boot, parsing, java-8

I am trying to parse through nested classes (POJO) and invoke a function which returns a double array using Java 8. 
Class structure is as below (Structure is to hold json input - which works fine)

```
creditcomplex {
                field 1;
                field 2;
                List<Borrower>;}

Borrower    {
                field 1;
                field 2;
                List<Facility>;}


Facility    {
                field 1;
                field 2;
                List<PaymentSchedule>;}
```

Method signature to be invoked ::  `double[] methodname (PaymentSchedule paymentSchedule) {}`

Requirement : invoke method for each facility if a PaymentSchedule exists in json.

Could you please let me know the most efficient way to traverse and obtain the returned result in Java 8 ?

---

Attempt (from comments)

```
for (Borrower borrower : borrowers) { 
    List<Facility> facilities = borrower.getFaciliies(); 
    for (Facility facility : facilities) { 
        List<RepaymentSchedule>repaymentScheduleList = facility.getrepaymentSchedule();
        if (repaymentScheduleList != null ){ 
            for(RepaymentSchedule repaymentschedule : repaymentScheduleList){ 

                double[] amortizationProfile = amortizationService.calculateAmortizationSchedule(repaymentschedule); 
                System.out.println("amortizationProfile : " + amortizationProfile); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us your attempts?

Comment: for (Borrower borrower : borrowers){
             List<Facility> facilities = borrower.getFaciliies();
             for (Facility facility : facilities){ List<RepaymentSchedule>repaymentScheduleList =facility.getrepaymentSchedule();
               if (repaymentScheduleList != null ){ for(RepaymentSchedule repaymentschedule : repaymentScheduleList){
                           double[] amortizationProfile = amortizationService.calculateAmortizationSchedule(repaymentschedule);
                           System.out.println("amortizationProfile : " + amortizationProfile);              }}}}

Comment: Above approach works but I would like to know the most efficient way using functional programming

Comment: Don’t post program code in comments, [edit] your question and add all necessary details.